# Grouping attributes together rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a destination model with following attributes :-

1) Continent 2) Country 3) City

I am doing something like this in the view :-

```
-@destinations.each do |d|
  =d.continent
  =d.country
  =d.city
```

I the result to be grouped together i.e :- I want all the cities which are in a country together and all the country which are in a continent. I want to display something like this :-

```
Asia
 India
  New delhi
  Lucknow
 China
  Beijing

Europe
 Greece
```

How to I go about achieving this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `group_by` [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) of the `Enumerable` class.

The idea would be to try something like

```
@destinations.group_by(&:continent).each do |continent, ds_per_continent|
  # print continent
  - ds_per_continent.group_by(&:country).each do |country, ds_per_country|
    # print country
    - ds_per_country.each do |destination|
      # print destination.city
```